# Make a non-raster glow in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, raster

I was wondering if it was possible to create a non-raster inner/outer glow? If so, could you please tell me how to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why it needs to be vector-based?  The Inner|Outer Glow effects in Illustrator work quite nicely when the document resolution is set fairly high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not launched Illustrator in a while, but there's one general solution:

1. copy your shape
2. shrink/expand it
3. make a flow transition of shape and color between first and second shapes
4. color first shape fully opaque white and second fully transparent white
5. tweak intermediate shapes count and/or colors
6. there's your inner/outer glow :)

Comment: line coloring and thickness is indeed an additional option, but is not good fit for a glow effect

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiples strokes with different colors and transparency in Adobe Illustrator. Simply create multiples strokes with different opacity values, set the blending mode that fits and progressively increase the weight of the stroke.

If you want an outer glow make sure the fill is in top of the stack in the Appereance palette. If you want a inner glow make sure the strokes alignment are set to "inside" in the stroke palette and the fill is in the bottom of the stack in the appereance palette.